# Version of Witness Server for mirroring SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

Can I use SQL 2008 R2 as a Witness Server for 2 instances of SQL 2012 Servers being mirrored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No witness server has to be SQL 2012, you can use SQL Express 2012 though

All server participating in database mirroring should be running same version of SQL server.

Taken from Microsoft SQL Server [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175191.aspx)

> Except during an upgrade from an earlier version of SQL Server, the
>   server instances in a mirroring session must all be running the same
>   version of SQL Server. For example, a SQL Server 2005 witness is
>   supported when you are upgrading from a SQL Server 2005 mirroring
>   configuration but cannot be added to an existing or new SQL Server
>   2008 or later mirroring configuration.

Database Mirroring will be deprecated in future release of SQL Server if possible use AlwasyOn Availability Group

Comment: Going to try using SQL 2012 Evaluation version - hoping that one will work. Thank you

Comment: Using Express in production is not a good move as it does not have a SQL Agent for starters. My 2c is that there is no way MS can count an additional license for a Witness.

Comment: @Slev I agree, now one technically has to go out and buy a licence purely to be a witness server. I also donot understand how sql versions has anything to do with a witness server? surely its a sort of ping program that just checks if it can reach the servers?